# C# dynamic anonymous JSON definition

Tags: c#, casting, json-deserialization, definition

I have a rather large JSON file I am attempting to parse and set definitions for in C#.  I am getting an error from the Newtonsoft JSON Deserializer.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value 151 to type 'QA_Test1.json.states'. Path 'MyFlow.states[1]', line 8378, position 15.'

-       InnerException  {"Could not cast or convert from System.Int64 to QA_Test1.json.states."}    System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
```

Because this element is an array [] and has a nested list, side by side with anonymous integers. I'm stuck here

```
"states": [
  { .. some more json data 
  },
  12,
  14,
  9,
  10
]
```

The first problem (1) I don't even need the integer data, I need the nested data but the Newtonsoft Deserializer is still trying to deserialize the integer data without a def.

The second problem (2) The "variables" element has anonymous elements also, I want to get the names example anonomousVarName1 and get the properties of that item. But I wont know what they are. So having a definition I am finding difficult.

```
"states": [
  { .. some more json data 
  },
  12, // problem 1
  14,
  9,
  10
],
"variables": {
        "anonomousVarName1": {
            "blah": ".VariableImpl",
            "blah": 407
            },
            "blah": false,
            "blah": null
        },
        "anonomousVarName2": {
            {
            "blah": ".VariableImpl",
            "blah": 407
            },
            "blah": false,
            "blah": null
            }
        }
```

My definition

```
public class state_connections
{
    [JsonProperty("states")]
    public List<states> states { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("variables")]
    public Dictionary<string, variables> variables { get; set; } // added resolution for problem 2
}
```

Problem #1 remains a huge issue
problem #2 is resolved by using

```
Dictionary<string, variables> variables {get; set;}
```

Accessing the Dictionary variables

```
connections_def file = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<connections_def>(_data_file, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, MaxDepth = 200, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
           
            foreach(var variable in file.automatonFlow.variables)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"Variable Key Name: {variable.Key}");
                Console.WriteLine("--- properties ---");
                Console.WriteLine($"    @class: {variable.Value.@class}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    @id: {variable.Value.id}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    defaultValue: {variable.Value.defaultValue}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    id: {variable.Value.long_id}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    name: {variable.Value.name}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    notes: {variable.Value.notes}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    secure: {variable.Value.secure}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    stateId: {variable.Value.stateId}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    type: {variable.Value.type}");
            }
```

Comment: Why don't you just read (`JsonTextReader`) the JSON file so that you have control on what you wanna read or not, instead of deserializing it? Or you should change the schema of the JSON file to make it more easily readable and/or deserializable.

Comment: Plus, if possible, try to work with a small amount of JSON data. Once your code works like a charm, you can test it with the whole 4Mb json content.

Comment: I already have it broken down thanks.

Comment: What if you use the type `Array` instead of a generic list `List<states>` ? You can add different type of values in an Array. You will have the json child-object and the integers values in it.

Comment: ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.Int64

Comment: Here is another idea : try using the type `List<object>` if `Array`does not work. I tried it and it looks like it worked well.

Comment: Do you know this tool https://json2csharp.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Rivo for your assistance as clearly this could not be done without implementing List object.  Still open to suggestions but here is what I found as a work-around and this is by far, a hack for a horribly designed JSON.

```
        foreach(var state in file.automatonFlow.states)
        {
            //check if object is actually the json I want and not the stupid integers
            if (state.GetType() == typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("--- states ---");

                //convert the object BACK into text
                var jobject = (JsonConvert.SerializeObject(state));

                //convert the data BACK into definition form
                states states = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<states>(jobject, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, MaxDepth = 200, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

                Console.WriteLine($"    @id: {states.id}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    actionClass: {states.actionClass}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    name: {states.name}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }   
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Definition

```
 public class connections_def
{
    [JsonProperty("states")]
    public List<object> states  { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("variables")]
    public Dictionary<string, variables> variables { get; set; }
}
```

---Outputs----

```
--- states ---

@id: 1
actionClass: HostCommandAction
name: Check Service running
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, using `List<object>` is more appropriate.

So your class definition should be :

```
public class state_connections
{
    [JsonProperty("states")]
    public List<object> states { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("variables")]
    public Dictionary<string,string> variables { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I solved problem 2, accessing the dynamic variable names using Dictionary, typed the first value to random string, and the known definitions for each by adding "variables"
[JsonProperty("variables")]
        public Dictionary<string, variables> variables { get; set; }

problem 1 List<object> for states excludes the class definition for states. There are a lot of properties within states and scales down to a dept of 194, I never seen a json with this depth before. So thissolution, while the filedeserializes, I lose the whole purpose of deserializing it by omitting the state def using object

Comment: But using List<object> is the only way I found to make it work.
You are not going to lose the access to the child-properties of any non-integer value in the deserialized object.
The debugger shows that the resulting value is of type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`, so may be if you lazy-load that resulting object by doing a nested deserialization, it might work.
What if you deserialize again the string representation of the first JSON node (before the integers) in a another instance property ?

Comment: I was considering that, to evaluate the object is not integer and then deserialize.

Comment: So was I. :-) I think that is the only way how you are going to overcome and solve this. Other than that, your case is very unsual. I never had that kind of problem before cause I usually work with a well-structured JSON code. So, at first, what I had in mind is either you change the JSON structure to make it easily deserializable, or you build your own deserializer or JSON structure reader class using the NewtonSoft's built-in classes, or you lazy-load in an instance C# property the result of the deserialization of sub-objects.